# How to host HTML file on Github pages in Nodejs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, hosting, github-pages

I am currently trying to host my html page (My Map.html) within my Node.js project. It is supposed to display a map, this file is not in a folder. I tried running the npm run build command in terminal and then deploying the page via GitHub Pages but it ends up displaying my ReadME file. What am I doing wrong and how can I get GitHub to ONLY display the HTML page in my Node.js/Typescript project?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by doing the following:

- Change `My Map.html` to `index.html`

In the root of my `package.json`, I added:

```json
"homepage": "https://{username.github.io}/{repo}",
```

Then I wrote `npm install --global gh-pages --save-dev`. I needed the `--global` to ensure the bin file is on my `PATH` and `--save-dev` should add it as a dependency in my `package.json`

After that, just `npm run build && gh-pages -d build`. The `-d` specified my output build directory. The standard is build, but mine was public. If it's different, just change it.

Lastly, I made sure in the Settings -> Pages section, that I selected gh-pages as the branch to host and leave the directory as / (root). It then worked after it deployed!

I found this answer from a user named Casey on a question asked over 10 years ago, hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

To host your HTML file on GitHub Pages within your Node.js project, follow these steps:

1. Create a `docs` folder: GitHub Pages will automatically publish content from a `docs` folder in your repository. Create a `docs` folder in the root of your Node.js project.
2. Move your HTML file: Move your `MyMap.html` file into the newly created `docs` folder.
3. Set up the `package.json` file: In your `package.json` file, add the following lines to specify the deployment path as the `docs` folder.

   "scripts": {
   "build": "your-build-command",
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d docs"
   }

Replace `your-build-command` with the actual command you use to build your project (e.g., `npm run build`, `ng build`, etc.).

4. Install `gh-pages` package: If you haven't already, install the `gh-pages` package, which helps you deploy to GitHub Pages.

   npm install gh-pages --save-dev
5. Deploy to GitHub Pages: Now, run the following command to build your project and deploy it to GitHub Pages.

   npm run deploy

After the deployment process is completed, your `MyMap.html` file should be accessible through GitHub Pages using the URL: `https://your-github-username.github.io/your-repo-name/MyMap.html`.

Ensure that your `MyMap.html` file references all necessary assets (CSS, JavaScript files, images, etc.) using correct relative paths to ensure they are loaded correctly when hosted on GitHub Pages.

By following these steps, only the HTML page (MyMap.html) from your Node.js project will be displayed on GitHub Pages, and other files, including the README, will not be shown.